# why Can't I save page from my ASP.net MVC website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, save

i've  builded an asp.net mvc website,when i click the "file->save page as" button in my browser and try to save the page as a local html file,there is no response and saving failed.why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost definitely a problem with the web browser.  Are you able to `Right Click -> View Source` on the page?

Comment: "view source"  works,i'll try different browsers,thanks for your reply